# Chi Square distribution with degree of freedom 3

Tags: r, degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution

For X following a Chi-square distribution with degree of freedom m = 3,

I want to compute P(1 < X < 4)

Would it be,

```
> x_range <-(1:4)
> sum(dchisq(x_range,df=3))
```

?

Comment: Despite the fact that chi-square is often used for discrete distributions, it is in fact a continuous distribution, so you would need to integrate. (...or more simply just take the differences using pchisq.) Voting to close as not really on-topic to be asking for help with your statistics homework.

Comment: @ would appreciate if you provide more insight rather than voting close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pchisq` function (whose help is on the same page as `dchisq`) gives the area to the left (or right with the right argument) of a value, in other words/symbols `pchisq(4,3)` would give $P(X < 4)$ for a chisquare with 3 degrees of freedom.  This is more than what you want by `pchisq(1,3)` so you just need to take the difference.

Comment: Thanks! If i want to use Monte Carlo Simulations to Check this with sample size n=100,00?

Comment: `set.seed(101); r <- rchisq(1e5,df=3); mean(r>1 & r<4)` vs `diff(pchisq(c(1,4),3))`